# Controlling decimal figures in Oracle query result

Tags: database, oracle

I'm trying to get my result (the percentage) to show in one or two decimal numbers
here's my query:

```
SELECT (SELECT Count(*)
        FROM   table_name
        WHERE  condition_1
               AND condition_2) / (SELECT Count(*)
                                   FROM   table_name) * 100 AS Percentage
FROM   table_name
WHERE  rownum = 1
```

The result is giving me:
5.8098402829885303891092292/8502519026691

Is there a way to get my result to look like 5.8 or 5.80 **without rounding up to 5.9 or 6**

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try trunc function with 1 as argument, alternatively with `fm` formatting upto two decimal digits added :

```
SELECT ( to_char(trunc(
        (SELECT Count(*)
           FROM   table_name
          WHERE  condition_1
            AND condition_2) / (SELECT Count(*)
                               FROM   table_name) * 100 
          ),1),'fm999G999G990D00') Percentage
FROM   table_name
WHERE  rownum = 1;
```

Comment: I tried using the TRUNC(percentage,1) but it is giving me an error,  [Error Code: 904, SQL State: 42000]  ORA-00904: "PERCENTAGE": invalid identifier

Comment: @MichaelB ok, i've edited, so that getting rid of extra nesting of sql, please try this.

Comment: Thank you for the edited query, it had an extra ( but I was able to take it out and it worked perfectly fine, thank you for the time you spent fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `ROUND(percentage,1)`

```
   SELECT ROUND (percentage, 1)
    FROM   (SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*)
                    FROM   table_name
                    WHERE  condition_1
                           AND condition_2) / (SELECT COUNT(*)
                                               FROM   table_name) * 100 AS
                   Percentage
            FROM   table_name
        WHERE  rownum = 1)
```

Comment: This did not work, forget about the percentage or what I'm trying to calulate, can you please tell me how can I get the result to display only 2 decimal digits ?

Comment: @MichaelB : Did you try `ROUND(yourvalue,2)` ?

Comment: @MichaelB : What do you mean by did not work.Please elaborate on that,

Comment: Ops, Sorry i just tried the ROUND(value,4) and it worked thank you

Comment: Ok, I will follow these guidelines, please accept my apology I'm new to this form and this is my second question.

Answer (score 0):

Actually using `ROUND(VALUE,4)`

```
SELECT ROUND((SELECT Count(*)
        FROM   table_name
        WHERE  condition_1
               AND condition_2) / (SELECT Count(*)
                                   FROM   table_name),4) * 100 AS Percentage
FROM   table_name
WHERE  rownum = 1;
```

displayed the result the way I wanted it, thanks to Kaushik Nayak, Thank you all

Comment: Your question makes it clear that you do not want to round up - you put it in bold.  In that case ROUND is not your friend - you can use TRUNC as @BarbarosÖzhan said in his original answer.  Can you update your question if the requirement has changed?

Comment: For some reason the data changed and when i Used the ROUND it did not round to the nearest whole number, instead it showed the full decimal number, are you saying that ROUND will round up my solution? because now my data display 86.44 which obviously will not round my answer since it's less than .5, but would it round it up if it was ?

Comment: @MichaelB i think you wanna ask a question to Christian Palmer, for this aim, you should start your comment with "@Christian Palmer", ok :) ?

Comment: Dear @BarbarosÖzhan, ok sorry, as I mentioned before I'm still new to this form and I'm still learning how to use it, so please bare with me while I learn, thank you

Comment: @MichaelB ROUND will follow the normal math rounding rules.  For one dp 86.44 will round to 86.4.  86.45 will round to 86.5.  For two dp 5.8098 will round to 5.81 not 5.80